# Screen numeric numbers in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Can somebody tell me is there any difference between next two quires?

First:

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = 10
```

Second

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '10'
```

So, if it's numeric value(int, double, float, decimal etc.) i used to ignore single quotes around it.

But some MySql clients(MySql workbench, MySql yok) recommends to put quotes even around numbers

Is there any performance difference, or maybe some recommendations which syntax to use?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the first query compares a number to a number and the second one compares a number to a string (apples vs. oranges). The recommendation to put quotes around numbers is a stupid one in my opinion and will fail badly if you ever use a DBMS that is more strict. Not sure about MySQL but most other DBMS might not be able to use an index if you compare apples to oranges.

Comment: you can use both but for numbers, it is expected to use without single quotes. however some database engines doesn't converts automatic numeric to string conversion for single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's just a safety factor, so that your query wont break, first rule will succeed only if the `id` field is `int`, if it's string it will fail, where second query will work for both, `string` as well as `int`

Though 1st rule is more stricter than the second one which is loose